# Execute src block on org mode export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have some sort of fundamental confusion about using src blocks in org mode.

I define a custom latex class in an emacs-lisp src block at the top of my org file. Export fails however, unless I manually execute the src block (because the required latex class doesn't exist until the src block is executed). I'm not prompted for permission to execute the block.

As a minimal example, I tried exporting this:

```
#+name: test
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "Success")
#+end_src
```

On export, I see `org-babel-exp processing...` in my messages buffer, and I would expect to see `"Success"` immediately after it, but I don't.

I'm clearly missing something obvious, but it's not clear to me from the info what I should be doing.

Comment: The code blocks don't get evaluated unless you [specifically tell org-mode to do it](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html). The snippet in your example will simply export to a code block in your chosen export format: pdf, html, etc. [**More on org-mode and source blocks**](http://orgmode.org/manual/Working-With-Source-Code.html).

Comment: That was the missing link. Adding `#+CALL: test()` to the example above gave me the expected behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code blocks don't get evaluated unless you [specifically tell Org mode to do it](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html) (or do `C-h i g (org)Evaluating Code Blocks` in Emacs). The snippet in your example will simply export to a code block in your chosen export format: pdf, html, etc.

[**More on Org mode and source blocks.**](https://orgmode.org/manual/Working-with-Source-Code.html) (or do `C-h i g (org)Working with Source Code` in Emacs)

Here is the modified version of your example with the required `#+CALL:` line and the good to have buffer local variable declaration to mark the execution of `emacs-lisp` snippets as safe.

```org
#+name: test
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "Success")
#+end_src
  
#+call: test()

# Local Variables:
# org-confirm-babel-evaluate: (lambda (lang body) (not (string= lang "emacs-lisp")))
# End:
```

Comment: What exactly is the "Local Variable" code doing again? What is it for?

Comment: @147pm - The local variable allows the emacs-lisp source block to execute during the export without prompting the user for confirmation. To disable confirmation for all languages, do `org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil` instead.

Comment: The links are expired. Also, is the default behaviour changed now? Because when I export an org file it always evaluate my code blocks.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav I have fixed the links and also suggested a better way of accessing the Org manual from within Emacs using the `C-h i g ..` (default) bindings.