# Is it possible to evaluate src blocks after export in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an `org-mode` file `foo.org`:

```
#+TITLE: My Title

Hello world!

#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports none
  with open('foo.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write('text appended!')
#+END_SRC
```

Issuing `C-c C-e t a` writes `foo.txt`. My python block should append the text `text appended!` to `foo.txt`. Is it possible to make this happen automatically upon export?

According to the answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/execute-src-block-on-org-mode-export), the code

```
#+TITLE: My Title

Hello world!

#+name: test
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports none
  with open('foo.txt', 'a') as f:
      f.write('text appended!')
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: test()
```

should work, but it is not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute src block on org mode export](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/execute-src-block-on-org-mode-export)

Comment: @erikstokes The answer to that question does not fix my problem. I've updated my question to address this.

Comment: It works for me with Emacs 25.2 and Org mode version 9.0.5 (release_9.0.5-81-g137c6a)